# Dynamically Insert Variable into value field

Tags: lightning-web-components

So I am trying to build a dynamic Navigation bar that I am passing a certain Knowledge URL in to go to our external knowledge base. I have the Property Value on the component which I will be able to put in the URL, but the problem I have is how can I get the value to populate correctly in the Lightning Formated URL?

```
<lightning-formatted-url value="{knowledgeURL}" label="Knowldege"></lightning-formatted-url>
```

in the .js file, I do have @api and in the meta.js file, I have a target set.

```
@api knowledgeURL ;
<property name="knowledgeURL" type="String" default=""></property>
```

Comment: What you are showing now is fine I think, what is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`value="{knowledgeURL}"` is not correct syntax for LWC. It should be `value={knowledgeURL}` without `"`. Install the salesforce LWC extensions so that you get to know these minor errors while saving itself.

```
<lightning-formatted-url value={knowledgeURL} label="Knowldege"></lightning-formatted-url>
```

You should install [Salesforce extension pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode) (recommended)

---

**OLD ANSWER**

If you check the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-url/example),

> Displays a URL with a protocol such as http:// and https://. Protocol
>   http:// is automatically prepended to a value like "my/path" to create
>   an absolute URL. A value "/my/path" creates a relative URL.

So, you can set url without `https://`

Sample code:

HTML:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <lightning-formatted-url value={knowledgeURL} label={knowledgeLabel}></lightning-formatted-url>
    </div>
</template>
```

JS:

```
@api knowledgeURL;
@api knowledgeLabel;
```

Comment: I think `@track` should be `@api` according to the users use case

Comment: The URL now is correctly working in the HTML. How can I get that variable from the Properties? I have it in the targetConfig and as a property, but how do I access this from the component?

Comment: @Gunner1714 added in answer - its syntax mistake. You should be using LWC extension

Comment: Also, the extension is included in the extension pack and should not be downloaded directly.

Comment: so with `@api` if the name of that is the same that should grab what is coming from the targetConfig property correct?

Comment: yes, you can try and check

Comment: @gNerb thanks! added in answer for extension pack

Comment: so I have a similar question but related to getting to the user profile page. Any suggestions on this?

I know the URL is /profile/:userId, would I do wire and then build the URL that way?

Comment: according to docs `A value "/my/path" creates a relative URL.` so you can give relative url also